# Where in Yosemite Valley was the shot of Kirk nearly hitting the ground filmed?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, real-location, the-final-frontier

As we know, an early scene in [Star Trek V: The Final Frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_V:_The_Final_Frontier) was shot in Yosemite Valley:

Kirk is supposed to be climbing El Capitan. I don't imagine for one second that Shatner was actually on the face of el Cap, although el Cap is in the shot.

At the end of the sequence, Kirk falls and nearly hits the ground. Where was this actually filmed? If you fall off el Cap, you hit a talus slope, not flat ground with a few rocks and trees.

This may be a very trivial point, but having just returned from my *n*th visit to Yosemite, I am curious.

Comment: That catch should pretty much have ripped his leg from his body.  Also, I love in Kirk's close-up how the "rock" looks suspiciously like grey paint over poorly made plaster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Shatner's book, "Star Trek Movie Memories",

[image]

the shot of him almost hitting the ground was filmed on a sound stage with him in a rig comfortably suspended a few feet off the ground.

> ◾Closeups of Kirk's fall were actually shot horizontally, then flipped so that they appeared vertical. 
>   https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_V:_The_Final_Frontier